# AWS S3 Java SDK - Access Denied

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to access a bucket and all its object using AWS SDK but while running the code i am getting an error as Exception in thread "main" `com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: X), S3 Extended Request ID: Y=`

Kindly suggest, where i am lacking and why access denied error is occurring although i have taken all following permission to the bucket:

```
s3:GetObject
s3:GetObjectVersion
s3:GetObjectAcl
s3:GetBucketAcl
s3:GetBucketCORS
s3:GetBucketLocation
s3:GetBucketLogging
s3:ListBucket
s3:ListBucketVersions
s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads
s3:GetObjectTorrent
s3:GetObjectVersionAcl
```

Code is as follows:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
clientConfig.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);
AmazonS3 conn = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, clientConfig);
conn.setEndpoint(bucketName);
Bucket bucket = conn.createBucket(bucketName);
ObjectListing objects = conn.listObjects(bucket.getName());
do {
    for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objects.getObjectSummaries()) {
            System.out.println(objectSummary.getKey() + "\t" +
                    objectSummary.getSize() + "\t" +
                    StringUtils.fromDate(objectSummary.getLastModified()));
    }
    objects = conn.listNextBatchOfObjects(objects);
} while (objects.isTruncated());
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is now solved. There were following issue to the code:

1. The end point was not correct, There should be a correct end point.
2. There was not enough permission given to the bucket. A list of complete permission should be taken before using the bucket in AWS SDK.

Below is the correct code

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
clientConfig.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);
AmazonS3 conn = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, clientConfig);
conn.setEndpoint("correct end point");
Bucket bucket = conn.createBucket(bucketName);
ObjectListing objects = conn.listObjects(bucket.getName());
do {
    for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objects.getObjectSummaries()) {
            System.out.println(objectSummary.getKey() + "\t" +
                    objectSummary.getSize() + "\t" +
                    StringUtils.fromDate(objectSummary.getLastModified()));
    }
    objects = conn.listNextBatchOfObjects(objects);
} while (objects.isTruncated());
```

Comment: Sorry to bring up the old post but still don't get why it worked with S3 browser but doesn't work in AWS SDK?

Comment: Can you explain the exact point of the issue coming with your code. It should work fine if you have done everything correctly.

Comment: I can access a folder inside of bucket using S3 Browser or CyberDuck but when I use aws sdk php to list keys with prefix I get                                                                           Uncaught Aws\S3\Exception\AccessDeniedException: AWS Error Code: AccessDenied, Status Code: 403

Comment: Can you make sure of following two points:

1.The end point you are using is correct, There should be a correct end point.

2.There are enough permission given to the bucket for a particular type of operation. A list of complete permission should be taken before using the bucket in AWS SDK.

Comment: Thanks It was the endpoint to get the list of keys. https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/?prefix=myfolder/&delimiter=/  I was missing the trailing slash for prefix

Answer (score 38):

Go to IAM and check whether the user [ Access Key & Secret Key ] which is being used for the API has the previliges to use S3 Based API.

Attached S3 Policy to the specified User - try with **S3 Full Access**; you can fine-grain the access once this works.
For More Information Check this Link [ [Managing IAM Policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/ManagingPolicies.html) ]

Comment: Hi am able to connect the same bucket using dragon disk and s3 browser but not through the code.

Comment: can you recheck whether you are using the same [ Access Key, Secret Key ] pair for both code & dragon disk ? Also check the bucket policy and Bucket Owner; Coz. they play a very vital role especially in access denied scenario.

Comment: Hi thanks, Now i am able to work actually problem was that i was not having the complete list of permissions to the bucket now i have taken all the permissions for AWS SDK and its working fine.

Comment: Hi, I have added permissions for everyone and seems working.

Comment: I am having same issue with the root user, I thought the root user have all access by default

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same exception and this is how I fixed it.

The S3 bucket objects were encrypted using service-side KMS. I had to add the app/lambda role as a user to the encryption key.

Comment: I also had encryption issues. the bucket policy wanted server side encryption and i was not specifying that when uploading.

Answer (score 0):

In permission tab of bucket, i uncheck:

> - Manage public access control lists (ACLs) for this bucket
> - Block new public ACLs and uploading public objects (Recommended)

and the problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you still see the error even after setting the right IAM policy and checking the bucket/path, check the apache http client dependency. The apache http client 4.5.5 works fine, while 4.5.7 and above fails for some weird reason (not properly encoding the folder path separators). You will have to explicitly set the apache http client version to 4.5.5 in that case.. or at least some other version that works.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This is save s3 buket image  code   




    byte imageBytes[] = request.getThumbnail().readAllBytes();  

    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);

    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    metadata.setContentLength(imageBytes.length);
    metadata.setContentType("image/png");
    String image = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    
    // String image=String.valueOf(System.getProperty(String.valueOf(inputRequest)));
    // String image=String.valueOf(System.getProperty(String.valueOf(inputRequest)));

    String key = "image/" + image;

    s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, inputStream, metadata)
      .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.Private));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check and add your region
[image]

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey");
AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1)
        .build();
```