# What is the right way to upload image to amazon s3 in android?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, image-upload

I used Following way to upload image to amazon s3. But i couldn't get succeed in this.

```
public UploadAmazon() {
    s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID,MY_SECRET_KEY));
    s3Client.createBucket(pictureBucket);
    s3Client.setBucketAcl(pictureBucket, CannedAccessControlList.valueOf("private"));
    uploadFile();
}

public void uploadFile() {
    PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(pictureBucket,"images/"+fileName,new File(fileURI));
    PutObjectResult result = s3Client.putObject(por);
}
```

When trying like this i'm getting following error

```
E/AndroidRuntime(31827): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
E/AndroidRuntime(31827): Process: com.xxx.yyy.zzz, PID: 31827
E/AndroidRuntime(31827): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime(31827):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
E/AndroidRuntime(31827):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
E/AndroidRuntime(31827):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
E/AndroidRuntime(31827):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
E/AndroidRuntime(31827):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
E/AndroidRuntime(31827):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/AndroidRuntime(31827):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(31827):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime(31827): Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 123456789), S3 Extended Request ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
E/AndroidRuntime(31827):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(31827):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(31827):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(31827):    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(31827):    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.createBucket(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(31827):    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.createBucket(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(31827):    at com.xxx.yyy.zzz.ftp.UploadAmazon.<init>(UploadAmazon.java:37)
E/AndroidRuntime(31827):    at com.xxx.yyy.zzz.NewMessageFragment$Uploading.doInBackground(NewMessageFragment.java:859)
E/AndroidRuntime(31827):    at com.xxx.yyy.zzz.NewMessageFragment$Uploading.doInBackground(NewMessageFragment.java:855)
E/AndroidRuntime(31827):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(31827):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(31827):    ... 4 more
```

i refered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139352/aws-s3-java-sdk-access-denied), but no success. Help Predicted. Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is clearly that you cannot write into that position. Have you checked bucket permission and policy?

Comment: @cigno5.5 this is my first attempt. please guide me in the correct way. i have access_key, secret_key, bucket, accessmode. what else i need to use. if these enough, how can i use them further?

Comment: have you already accessed to http://aws.amazon.com/console/ ? In there you can setup everything about services from aws. 
There are many ways to configure permissions but you should try as first step directly on the console

Answer (score 0):

Found the way.

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID,MY_SECRET_KEY);
TransferManager manager = new TransferManager(credentials);
Upload upload = manager.upload(pictureBucket,"images/"+fileName,new File(fileURI));
```

This will do..