# copy file from one bucket to other bucket using java aws sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i used following  code to copy file from one bucket to other bucket

```
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
s3client.copyObject(sourceBucketName, sourceKey, 
                    destinationBucketName, destinationKey);
```

but i alway get 
"com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: B6466D562B6988E2)"` as the respone what may be the reason for that

Comment: Maybe `Error Code: AccessDenied`

Comment: what? Error Code: AccessDenied

Comment: i have read and write permission then how access denied?

Comment: Where are you getting the credentials -- is the code running on an Amazon EC2 instance with an attached Role, or are you supplying credentials in a configuration file? Do those credentials have permission to read the source object and to write the destination object? What are the Bucket Policies on each bucket and/or what IAM permissions have been assigned? (You can update your Question to show the permissions.) What do you mean by "I have read and write permissions" -- how are they assigned? Basically, the error message is saying that something doesn't have sufficient permissions.

Comment: "i have read and write permission " meant that using that access token i can read and write to that specific bucket

Answer (score -1, accepted):

now i copy the file using java aws sdk
This is due to the absence of meta data while cpoying the file so we must add the meta data using copy `copyObjRequest.setNewObjectMetadata(objectMetadata);`
ref 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/SSEUsingJavaSDK.html for the details

Answer (score 1):

There can be lot of possibilities for getting such an error (like non-existent bucket, permissions issues, custom policy applied on source or target buckets etc.) I will recommend to setup [AWS S3 CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) on your machine and try different [s3 commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/) to make sure that you actually have right set of permissions to do the operation. This will allow you to iterate fast and debug issue quickly. I am not against writing Java code here to do the same but cli will definitely save time for you.

Also look this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139352/aws-s3-java-sdk-access-denied) to see if this helps you in fixing your problem.

Comment: l have listed the bucket and file name there is exists also the permission i have read and write permission, also i can dowload and upload files. but i doesnot allow any copy operation

Comment: Can you try CLI and share what happens on:
aws s3 cp s3://sourceBucketName/sourceKey s3://destinationBucketName/destinationKey ?

Comment: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: Access Denied as the output

Comment: It looks like you are using wrong set of credentials. Can you do a list of objects on your S3 bucket?